ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn.myapp'
I am trying to make two apps accessible on my LAN server (raspberry pi).

lab_app: this one is a very simple app, made with flask from a third party, using a sqlite3 database, which results to be a file inside my app folder. It is located at path /var/www/lab_app/ and runs on internal port 8080, external port 80.

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)


aqi_luftdaten: a more complex app, made with django by me, using postgresql database. It is located at path /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/ and runs on internal port 8000 - I have manually started it via command:
python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000


For the moment, only lab_app is working and accessible:
Its web server is nginx and its application server is uWSGI.
nginx is configured in this way:
there is a configuration file /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_nginx.conf which is pointed by a simbolic link from directory /etc/nginx/conf.d
ln -s /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

Its content is
    server {
        listen      80;
        server_name localhost;
        charset     utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 75M;

        location /static {
            root /var/www/lab_app/;
        }

        location / { try_files $uri @labapp; }
        location @labapp {
            include uwsgi_params;
            uwsgi_pass unix:/var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.sock;
        }
    }

by following a tutorial, I have removed the default nginx sites-enabled config file, so that the directory /etc/nginx/sites-enabled is void.
Inside the directory /etc/nginx/sites-available/ there is only the default file /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.
Its content is
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;

        root /var/www/html;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name _;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }

    }

uWSGI is configured in this way:
there is a file /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.ini having content:
    [uwsgi]
    #application's base folder
    base = /var/www/lab_app

    #python module to import
    app = lab_app
    module = %(app)

    home = %(base)
    pythonpath = %(base)

    #socket file's location
    socket = /var/www/lab_app/%n.sock

    #permissions for the socket file
    chmod-socket    = 666

    #the variable that holds a flask application inside the module imported at line #6
    callable = app

    #location of log files
    logto = /var/log/uwsgi/%n.log

I have loaded its information to uWSGI by using the command
bin/uwsgi --ini /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.ini

and then there is a file /etc/systemd/system/emperor.uwsgi.service having content
    [Unit]
    Description=uWSGI Emperor
    After=syslog.target

    [Service]
    ExecStart=/var/www/lab_app/bin/uwsgi --ini /var/www/lab_app/lab_app_uwsgi.ini
    # Requires systemd version 211 or newer
    RuntimeDirectory=uwsgi
    Restart=always
    KillSignal=SIGQUIT
    Type=notify
    StandardError=syslog
    NotifyAccess=all

    [Install]
    WantedBy=multi-user.target

This app runs fine on my LAN and is reachable at my server's ip from an external device browser.
Now I would like to expose app aqi_luftdaten on external port 80.
So the first thing I want to do is to configure nginx for this app.
So I have created an nginx config file /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/nginx/aqi_luftdaten_nginx.conf, having content
    server {
        listen      3000;
        server_name localhost;
        charset     utf-8;
        client_max_body_size 75M;

        location /static/ {
            root /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/static/;
        }

        location / { 
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        }
    }

and linked it symbolically to directory /etc/nginx/conf.d/ via
ln -s /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/nginx/aqi_luftdaten_nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/

then restart nginx
/etc/init.d/nginx restart

and I get
[ ok ] Restarting nginx (via systemctl): nginx.service.

If I try to reach the aqi_luftdaten application in the browser of another device http://<raspberrypi_IP>:3000/ I get
    <html><head><title>502 Bad Gateway</title></head>
    <body bgcolor="white">
    <center><h1>502 Bad Gateway</h1></center>
    <hr><center>nginx/1.14.2</center>
    </body></html>

which I guess is right, since the uWSGI is not configured yet.
now I would like to configure gunicorn.
There is a file /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/gunicorn/aqi_luftdaten.wsgi having the following content:
    import os
    from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

    # environment settings for Django app
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'aqi_luftdaten.settings')

    # Initialize app Django
    application = get_wsgi_application()

so I run
sudo su
cd /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/
source venv/bin/activate
sudo venv/bin/gunicorn gunicorn.aqi_luftdaten.wsgi:application --bind localhost:8000

but I get
[2024-04-01 14:48:20 +0100] [7595] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
[2024-04-01 14:48:20 +0100] [7595] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (7595)
[2024-04-01 14:48:20 +0100] [7595] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2024-04-01 14:48:20 +0100] [7597] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7597
[2024-04-01 14:48:20 +0100] [7597] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/aqi_luftdaten/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/var/www/aqi_luftdaten/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/var/www/aqi_luftdaten/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/var/www/aqi_luftdaten/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/var/www/aqi_luftdaten/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/var/www/aqi_luftdaten/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/var/www/aqi_luftdaten/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
    mod = importlib.import_module(module)
  File "/usr/local/opt/python-3.8.1/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gunicorn.aqi_luftdaten'
[2024-04-01 14:48:20 +0100] [7597] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 7597)
[2024-04-01 14:48:20 +0100] [7595] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2024-04-01 14:48:20 +0100] [7595] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.

so it seems it cannot find my file /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/gunicorn/aqi_luftdaten.wsgi , but I don't understand why.
I have also tried to launch
venv/bin/gunicorn gunicorn.aqi_luftdaten.wsgi:application --bind localhost:8000

without the sudo, but the error remains

By following this thread , I have moved my file /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/gunicorn/aqi_luftdaten.wsgi to /var/www/aqi_luftdaten/aqi_luftdaten.wsgi and then runned
PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. venv/bin/gunicorn aqi_luftdaten.wsgi:application --bind localhost:8000

and now the app works and is reachable at http://<RaspberryIP>:3000/ from any external device browser connected to the LAN
